# Google Admin Directory API - Granting access to service account using google sheets script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-directory-api

I have a script that pulls user data from the directory and pushes it to a google sheet. I keep getting an error that I don't have access and have tried everything. I have no idea why.

Here's my code:

```
    var PRIVATE_KEY =
    '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY--------END PRIVATE KEY-----\n';
var CLIENT_EMAIL = 'contacts@automation.iam.gserviceaccount.com';
var USER_EMAIL = 'admin@domain.com';


function getService() {
  return OAuth2.createService('Domain:' + USER_EMAIL)
      // Set the endpoint URL.
      .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')

      // Set the private key and issuer.
      .setPrivateKey(PRIVATE_KEY)
      .setIssuer(CLIENT_EMAIL)

      // Set the name of the user to impersonate. This will only work for
      // Google Apps for Work/EDU accounts whose admin has setup domain-wide
      // delegation:
      // https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority
      .setSubject(USER_EMAIL)

      // Set the property store where authorized tokens should be persisted.
      .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties())

      // Set the scope. This must match one of the scopes configured during the
      // setup of domain-wide delegation.
      .setScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly');
}

function listAllUsers() {

  var service = getService();
  if (service.hasAccess()) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var pageToken,
    page,
    count = 0;
    var listArray = [];
    listArray.push(['full name', 'first name', 'last name', 'email', 'orgunit', 'department', 'title', 'phoneType', 'phoneNumber', 'ID'])
    do {
        page = AdminDirectory.Users.list({
                domain: "domain.com",     // Google Apps domain name
                orderBy: "email",     
                pageToken : pageToken
            });
        var users = page.users;
        if (users) {
            for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
                var user = users[i];
                var department,
                title, phonetype, phonenumber, orgunit; // Addded two new variables 
                try { // Try to get the users department if there is an error push the error to the array
                    department = user.organizations[0].department;
                } catch (e) {
                    department = e
                }
                try {// Try to get the users title if there is an error push the error to the array
                    title = user.organizations[0].title;
                } catch (e) {
                    title = e
                }
              try {// Try to get the users PhoneType if there is an error push the error to the array
                    phonetype = user.phones[0].type;
                } catch (e) {
                    title = e
                }
              try {// Try to get the users PhoneNumber if there is an error push the error to the array
                    phonenumber = user.phones[0].value;
                } catch (e) {
                    title = e
                }
              try {// Try to get the users PhoneNumber if there is an error push the error to the array
                    orgunit = user.organizations[0].name;
                } catch (e) {
                    title = e
                }
                listArray.push([user.name.fullName, user.name.givenName, user.name.familyName, user.primaryEmail, orgunit, department, title, phonetype, phonenumber, user.id]);

            }
        }
        pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
         // This means you only get one page
    } while (pageToken);
    try {
        var outputSheet = ss.getSheetByName('allMembers');
        outputSheet.getDataRange();
    } catch (err) {
        var outputSheet = ss.insertSheet('allMembers', 2);
    }
    outputSheet.getDataRange().clear();
    outputSheet.getRange(1, 1, listArray.length, listArray[0].length).setValues(listArray);
    outputSheet.getRange(1, 6, outputSheet.getLastRow(), 4).setHorizontalAlignment("center");
    outputSheet.getRange(1, 1, outputSheet.getLastRow(), 1).setHorizontalAlignment("center");
    var width = [150, 150, 180, 250, 250, 200];
  } }
```

When I run it with the viewtype domain_public it works, but only pulls global directory data and not hidden data like organization units.

I get the error Not Authorized to access this resource/api (line 41, file "Code")

I made sure that the advanced services and API is enabled for the project, the service account has domain wide delegation with scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly

and I still can't seem to get it to work no matter what I try.

I tried adding the auth code from https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2 but as you can see, it still doesn't work.

Comment: You want to use the method of list in Directory API using service account. If my understanding is correct, in your script, you are using ``AdminDirectory.Users.list()`` with Advanced Google Services. In this case, your account is used instead of the service account. So when you want to use the method of list with the service account, it is required to directly request to the endpoint using [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) by including the access token retrieved from the service account. If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.